# Set text color of one element to bg color of another element

Tags: jquery, css, jscolor

I'm trying to create the illusion of transparent text in a colorpicker by dynamically setting the text color to match the background color.

There seems to be something wrong with the last line of jquery.
So far, what I have is this:

```
$('.color').blur(function()
{
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id.substring(0,id.length-6);
    $(id).css('color',$(this).css('background-color'));
});
```

and

```
<div id="header-wrapper">
    <input class="color" id="header-wrapper-color" value="#303030">
    <div id="header">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your selector is wrong, if you select by id yo have to add a prefix of `#` to the selector

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('#'+id).css('color',$(this).css('background-color'));
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/RpqUj/)

Comment: Ugh, I can't believe I missed that. Thanks!