# jQuery, set background color of a table element to color of previous element?

Tags: jquery, colors, background, html-table

I'd like to dynamically set the background color of a div equal to the background color of the table row that directly proceeded it. Here's what I think I want to do:

```
$(this).next().css('background-color', $(this).css('background-color'));
```

When looking for an answer on this board, I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674724/set-text-color-of-one-element-to-bg-color-of-another-element). This seems to be the answer that worked for them, but mine doesn't work. Any suggestions gratefully accepted.

EDIT

For those  who have asked to see what I'm trying to do, here is the PHP code that is building the body of my table:

```
<?php
//  For every row past the first (header) row, create a table entry
    while ( $row = fgetcsv($handle) ) {

        echo "<tr class='c_edd_row'>";                      
        //  Build each cell         
        $num = count($row);         
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            //  Do not echo entries 23 through 27 (unused cells)
           if ( $c < 23 || $c > 27 ) {
              echo "<td>".$row[$c]."</td>";
              //  save the last entry for the hidden div
              $validation_notes = $row[$c];
          }
        }
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr class='c_sub_row'>
        <td colspan='42' class='c_notes_div'>
        <div class='c_notes_div'>".$validation_notes."</div>
        </td></tr>";
    }
?>
```

Responders were correct, I didn't state my problem very well. The divs I was talking about are actually contained in TRs. I'm using this as a dropdown for every row with data in the last row entry.

When I click a row, the following row with class c_sub_row changes from display:none to display:table-row, which works great, but I need it to take the color of the proceeding row when that happens.

FINAL UPDATE - Big thanks to Jonathan Sampson

Here is the final solution, based on the comments below:

```
$('.c_edd_row').on('click',  function(event) {
    var bg = $(this).css("background-color");
    $(this).next().css("background-color", bg);   //  colors the next row
    $(this).next().find('div').css("background-color", bg);  //  colors the div
});
```

Comment: Could you please provide a simple HTML structure that describes what you want? Your description is not very clear.

Comment: usually a div element is not meant to be next to a <tr> element, and that's why that could isnt working for you, because it reads the backgroundcolor property of the element RIGHT AFTER current element. As Lior say we need to see the html to refine the code for you

Comment: IS your element a children (same as the table) or is he the parent element of the table?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Hopefully the edit I posted will show you how my table is built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table rows never directly precede `div` elements - that would be invalid table markup. If you wanted to set the background of a tr to that of the tr that preceded it, you could do the following:

```
$("tr:eq(1)").css("background-color", function(){
  return $(this).prev().css("background-color");
});
```

Or perhaps you have a `div` within a `tr`, and you want the `div` to have the same background color as the `tr` that precedes the parent of the `div`:

```
$(this).css("background-color", function(){
  return $(this).closest("tr").prev().css("background-color");
});
```

Where `this` is the current `div` element.

The magic here happens in the anonymous function used as the second argument to the `$.css` method. From within it you can do just about anything. For instance, we could pick out any other element on the page and copy its background color:

```
$(this).css("background-color", function(){
  return $(".someOtherDiv").css("background-color");
});
```

Again, assuming `this` is our target `div` element, it will now have the same background color as `<div class="someOtherDiv">...</div>`.

#### Update

From the comments, it sounds like you have two table rows (at least). One visible, and the next one hidden. Within the second one, you have a div. When you click the first (visible) table row, you want to both show the second and apply the bg of the first TR to the DIV within the second (now visible) table-row:

```
$("tr:visible").on("click", function(event){
  var bg = $(this).css("background-color");
  $(this).next().show().find("div").css("background-color", bg);
});
```

Comment: Your #2 solution describes perfectly what I'm trying to do, but the code doesn't quite work - it actually sets the clicked row equal to the following div, the reverse of what I want. I'll keep gnawing on your code, but any further advice would be appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: So you have two `div` elements, immediately side-by-side (`<div>foo</div><div>bar</div>`). When you click the second, you want it to get the background of the first?

Comment: No, I have a table row with display:none after every visible row, and the hidden row contains a div. The div is just a convenient container for some stuff I want to display. When I click on a visible row, the row beneath it becomes visible, and the div with it. It is this hidden (now visible) row and the div it contains that I'd like to take on the bg color of the clicked row above it.

Comment: @Stanton Please see my update, and correct any misunderstanding I might have.

Comment: Dude, I think you pegged it. I made some slight changes (mostly to accommodate other things I was doing), and I have it working perfectly. I've updated my original post if you'd like to look at (and comment on, if you're so inclined) my code. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".your_table_class tr:last-child").each(function(){
    $(this).parent().next().css('background-color', $(this).css('background-color'));
 })

});
```

Here `.your_table_class` is the class/dummy class that is used in all those tables whose next div is to be colored. Remember the div should be immediate next element to the table.

Also if your table contains `<tbody>` tag then the line would be `$(this).parent().parent().next().css('background-color', $(this).css('background-color'));`

Answer (score 1):

#### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/aqotix/edit#javascript,html,live)*

```
var neededBG = $('#children_table tr').css('background-color');   // cache the needed color
$('#children_div').css({backgroundColor: neededBG });             // use of the needed color
```